# There is an error in XML document (2, 2): how to deserialize this xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a xml-document that needs to be deserialized into an object with a `XmlSerializer`:

The method that does this work takes a default namespace and a xml string:

```
public static T Deserialize(string xml, string defaultNamespace)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
    object obj;
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        obj = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        stringReader.Close();
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
```

When the default namespace "http://www.defaultnamespace.com/xsd/MyObject12" is passed with the following xml string: (where new lines are "\n\r")

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:MyObject12 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/xsd/example11" 
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/xsd/MyObject12">
  <Status xmlns="some:stuff">
    <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
  </Status>
</ns:MyObject12>
```

the following exception is thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
> Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
> Inner exception: {< MyObject12 xmlns='http://www.example.com/xsd/MyObject12'> was not expected."}

I tried to fix it by prepending  `ns:` to all xml elements, but the same error occured.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: I'm just guessing (sorry): isn't namespace usable only in elements that are children/descendants to the one that declares it? So it should by <MyObject12><ns:whatever/></MyObject12> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code. It's working properly. only change it did is removed `<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` from xml string.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string xml = @"<ns:MyObject12 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:ns1='http://example.com/xsd/example11' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:ns='http://www.example.com/xsd/MyObject12'><Status xmlns='some:stuff'><StatusCode>0</StatusCode></Status></ns:MyObject12>";
            var myObject12 = Deserialize<MyObject12>(xml, "http://www.example.com/xsd/MyObject12");
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml, string defaultNamespace)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
            object obj;
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                obj = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                stringReader.Close();
            }
            return (T)obj;
        }


    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MyObject12
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
```